# как отправить файл на бек вместе с дополнительными полями?

Tags: javascript, php, axios, fileupload, formdata

у меня есть формочка на странице. когда файл добавляется в input:file то файл оттуда (инстанс класса File) добавляется в FormData и input:file очищается для дальнейшего выбора нового файла. при добавлении файла делается следующее

```js
const addFileToList = (inputFile) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    const uploadedFile = inputFile.files[0] // файл из инпута File{...}
    const uploadedFileWrapper = {}

    uploadedFileWrapper.file = uploadedFile
    uploadedFileWrapper.foo = 'foo'
    uploadedFileWrapper.bar = 'bar'

    formData.append('files[]', uploadedFileWrapper)


    clearInputForm()
    axios.post('localhost://foobarbaz/upload-file', formData)
}
```

и вот при отправке запроса на бек приходит структура вида

```php
"files" => array:1 [
    0 => "[object Object]"
]
```

потом я попробовал сделать так

```js
formData.append('files[]', JSON.stringify(uploadedFileWrapper))
```

и получил это

```php
"files" => array:2 [
    0 => "{"file":{}, "foo": "foo", "bar": "bar"}"
]
```

т.е. файл опять пустой файл. ну и я ожидаю получить на беке такой результат

```php
"files" => array:1 [
    0 => [
        "file" => UploadedFile...,
        "foo"  => "foo",
        "bar"  => "bar",
    ],
]
```

ну увы у меня не получается. ну вот и вот вопрос **как отправить на бек файл вместе с дополнительными полями которые привязаны к загружаемому файлу?**

p.s. реально очень интересно. попробуйте сами так объект с файлом отправить на бек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

функция должна быть такая

```js
const addFileToList = (inputFile) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    const uploadedFile = inputFile.files[0] // файл из инпута File{...}
    const uploadedFileWrapper = {}

    // внимание на ключи
    formData.append('files[][file]', uploadedFile)
    formData.append('files[][foo]', 'foo')
    formData.append('files[][bar]', 'bar')


    clearInputForm()
    axios.post('localhost://foobarbaz/upload-file', formData)
}
```

и вот теперь если загрузить 2 файла то на беке можно получить такую структуру

```php
"files" => array:2 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "file" => UploadedFile...,
      "foo" => "foo",
      "bar" => "bar",
    ],
    1 => array:3 [
      "file" => UploadedFile...,
      "foo" => "foo1",
      "bar" => "bar1",
    ],
]
```